# Installing QGIS 3.22 on 32-bit Linux system

Tags: qgis, installation, linux, 32bit

Is it possible to install the new QGIS version 3.22 on a 32-bit Linux system?

I tried to install it with this procedure (in the Linux terminal):

```
sudo apt install gnupg software-properties-common

wget -qO - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2021.gpg.key | sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/qgis-archive.gpg --import
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/qgis-archive.gpg

sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu $(lsb_release -c -s) main"

sudo apt update

sudo apt install qgis
```

The result was installation of QGIS 3.18. I know, that on Windows systems QGIS only supports the version QGIS 3.18. But on Linux systems 32-bit?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you have?

Comment: On the 32-bit laptop I have mx linux 19-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible because MX Linux 19-4 is based in Buster Debian. You can see all requirements for QGIS 3.20 [here](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu). You have to upgrade to MX Linux 21 version based in Debian "Bullseye". More information in following link:

https://www.debugpoint.com/2021/10/mx-linux-21-release/

For reference, **/etc/apt/sources.list** in my Debian 11 looks  as follows for including last version of QGIS 3.20 in repositories:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ bullseye-security main contrib non-free

deb     https://qgis.org/debian bullseye main
deb-src https://qgis.org/debian bullseye main
```

Comment: thanks a lot, xunilk! Before your post I had tried to upgrade mxlinux 19.4 to mxlinux 21 (without fresh installation), but I used a wrong sources.list! With your sources.list the upgrade seemed to work. Though it did not come to an end, therefore I had to make a fresh installation. After that the installation of QGIS 3.22 was easy!

Comment: You're welcome. So, I appreciate you mark this answer as accepted.